# How to detect custom errors

Tags: go, error-handling

## Motivation

I have custom error type named **CustomError** and I want to write a method that parses any type of error into my error structure. So I wrote **parse** method to show you. I will use the **parse** method on any function that returns **error** interface. So all errors will be structured with my type.

## Problem

When I use **parse** method with nil value to return **error** interface, the returning error is not nil. Code is below. First test succeeded but second did not.

```golang
const (
    UnHandledError      = "UnHandledError"
    CircuitBreakerError = "CircuitBreakerError"
)

type CustomErrorType struct {
    Key     string
    Message string
    Status  int
}

func (c *CustomErrorType) Error() string {
    return "Custom error message"
}

func parse(err error) *CustomErrorType {
    if err == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if e, ok := err.(*CustomErrorType); ok {
        return e
    }
    if e, ok := err.(hystrix.CircuitError); ok {
        return &CustomErrorType{CircuitBreakerError, e.Message, http.StatusTooManyRequests}
    }
    return &CustomErrorType{UnHandledError, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError}
}

func TestParse_it_should_return_nil_when_error_is_nil(t *testing.T) {
    result := parse(nil)
    if result != nil {
        t.Error("result is not nil")
    }
}

func TestParse_it_should_return_nil_when_error_is_nil_2(t *testing.T) {
    aFunc := func() error {
        return parse(nil)
    }
    result := aFunc()
    if result != nil {
        t.Error("result is not nil")
    }
}
```

Can you explain what am I missing or what is wrong?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of a common "*problem*" of go's interfaces that is caused by the actual implementation of interfaces under the hood: an interface containing a `nil` pointer is not-`nil`.

it is described in go's faq with an example that resembles your situation with the `error` interface: [Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error)

> Under the covers, interfaces are implemented as two elements, a type `T` and a value `V`. `V` is a concrete value such as an `int`, `struct` or `pointer`, never an interface itself, and has type `T`.
>
> ...
>
> An interface value is `nil` only if the `V` and `T` are both unset, `(T=nil, V is not set)`, In particular, a `nil` interface will always hold a `nil` type. If we store a `nil` pointer of type `*int` inside an interface value, the inner type will be `*int` regardless of the value of the pointer: `(T=*int, V=nil)`. Such an interface value will therefore be non-nil even when the pointer value `V` inside is `nil`.
>
> This situation can be confusing, and arises when a `nil` value is stored inside an interface value such as an error return:
>
> ```
> func returnsError() error {
>   var p *MyError = nil
>   if bad() {
>       p = ErrBad
>   }
>   return p // Will always return a non-nil error.
> }
> ```

this example is similar to what is happening in your code when you do:

```
aFunc := func() error {
    return parse(nil)
}
```

`parse()` returns `*CustomErrorType`, but the function just `error` making the value returned an interface that contains a type and a `nil` value: `(T=*CustomErrorType, V=nil)` that in turn evaluates to not-`nil`.

the faq then goes on providing explanation and showing a "correct" example:

> If all goes well, the function returns a `nil` p, so the return value is an `error` interface value holding `(T=*MyError, V=nil)`. This means that if the caller compares the returned `error` to `nil`, it will always look as if there was an error even if nothing bad happened. To return a proper `nil` error to the caller, the function must return an explicit `nil`:
>
> ```
> func returnsError() error {
>   if bad() {
>       return ErrBad
>   }
>   return nil
> }
> ```

the behavior can also be observed in your example adding a

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", result)
```

to print `result`'s value:

```
(*e.CustomErrorType)(nil)
```

if we change `parse()` return type to just `error` it will print:

```
<nil>
```